# Download a SharePoint Folder

Tags: download

How Can I **download** a SharePoint *folder* included with documents?
 I understand how I can download a document from SP but I'm wondering if I can do the same with a folder.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Use the **Open with Explorer** option available at the ribbon row. With the Explorer view open, you can copy+paste the folder in total to your local files, which does the same functionality as downloading would.
2. Use SharePoint Designer to access the folder's path, where you can also download the folder with all of its contents.

Comment: 3. Or you can sync you folders using one drive and then copy paste into your local system. Any of these 3 methods are fine as mentioned by @moe above